# Mock AWS SES using jest in typeorm

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, typeorm, amazon-ses

Need to test AWS SES using jest unit testing
But showing different errors, also tried solutions in another stackoverflow question
The actual code to be tested is :

```
public async sentMail(params: ObjectLiteral) {

 // Create the promise and SES service object
    const sendPromise = new AWS.SES({ apiVersion: '2010-12-01' })
      .sendEmail(params)
      .promise();

    // Handle promise's fulfilled/rejected states
    sendPromise
      .then(function (data) {
        console.log(data.MessageId);
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        console.error(err, err.stack);
      });
```

the test file is :

```
import SES from 'aws-sdk/clients/ses';
const mSES = {
    sendEmail: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    promise: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    catch: jest.fn(),
  };
  jest.mock('aws-sdk/clients/ses', () => {
    return jest.fn(() => mSES);
  });

it('should send aws sesemail', async () => {
      // const spy = jest.spyOn(AWS, 'SES');
      const mSes = new SES() as unknown as {
        sendEmail: jest.Mock;
        promise: jest.Mock;
      };
      mSes
        .sendEmail()
        .promise.mockRejectedValueOnce(new Error('This is an SES error'));
      const res = await sesMailService.sentMail(
        {
          toName: 'Name',
          webUrl: 'webUrl',
        },
      );
      expect(mSes.sendEmail).toBeCalledWith({
          toName: 'Name',
          webUrl: 'webUrl',
        }
);
    });
```

Its giving error message as:

```
TypeError: mSes.sendEmail(...).promise.mockRejectedValueOnce is not a function

      94 |       mSes
      95 |         .sendEmail()
    > 96 |         .promise.mockRejectedValueOnce(new Error('This is an SES error'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this mock works, the reason behind the error is that , i didn't mocked the AWS.Credentials.

```
jest.mock('aws-sdk', () => {

  return {

    config: {

      update() {

        return {};

      },

    },

    SES: jest.fn(() => {

      return {

        sendEmail: jest.fn((param) => {

          return {

            promise: () =>

              new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

                param?.Destination.ToAddresses[0] !== 'invalidmail@gmail.com'

                  ? resolve({

                      MessageId: data.MessageId,

                    })

                  : reject(err);

              }),

          };

        }),

      };

    }),

    Credentials: jest.fn(),

  };

});
```